# Dynamic sheet name in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have been tasked to create a spreadsheet for weekly salary calculations of every company worker. I want to create a spreadsheet with one sheet for every week number of 2022 and name it accordingly. Since I'd have to create 52 sheets named "WN 01" to "WN52" I was looking for a shorter way to do this.

But what's even more time consuming is using data of all these sheets. What I want is a table like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| = 'WN01' !$A$1 | = 'WN01' !$B$1 | = 'WN01' !$C$1 |
| = 'WN02' !$A$1 | = 'WN02' !$B$1 | = 'WN02' !$C$1 |
| = 'WN03' !$A$1 | = 'WN03' !$B$1 | = 'WN03' !$C$1 |
| = 'WN04' !$A$1 | = 'WN04' !$B$1 | = 'WN04' !$C$1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| = 'WN52' !$A$1 | = 'WN52' !$B$1 | = 'WN52' !$C$1 |

Is there a way to dynamically/automatically change the used sheet name? Is there a script or add-on I could use that basically adds +1 to the sheet name used in every row?
I tried using a macro to do this, but that wasn't very successfull.

I hope you can help me with my problem!

Comment: There are "tricks" you could use to do this. However, I always find myself cringing inside when I read that people are planning to have a sheet per week and then try to compile 52 sheets into a master. I know that *feels* right. But it's backward (99.5% of the time). Rather, all data for all weeks should be normalized such that it can be entered in rows within *one sheet only*; and then (probably) *one* additional sheet can be used to select data for any given week or period and display/manipulate it into a report, and *one* additional sheet can be set up as a master for YTD (if needed).

Comment: If you are set on getting A1:C52 filled as shown in your post, report back and I'll explain how to do it. It will take a few simple steps that I'd need to explain. If that is the case, please confirm that you want 52 rows by 3 columns of this pattern. If not, be specific about how many columns should follow this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You want to report data from weekly sheets (names "WN01"-"WN52"). This answer takes your request at face value.

There are many possible solutions to this question. Please consider this as just one approach.

- Use this formula in Cell A1:
  `=indirect("wn0"&row()&"!$"&REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(row(), Column()),"[A-Z]+")&"$"&column())`
- Copy the formula across as many columns (and down as many rows) as required.

---

**Logic**
The formula is constructed from several functional elements

- `indirect` - returns the value from the string value of a cell reference.

So the following elements create a dynamic string value of the respective addresses

- `wn0` - the three character prefix of every sheet
- `row()` - since the data begins in Cell A1, `row()` will return a value that creates a unique sheet name on every row.
- `&"!$"&` - Adds a sheet suffix and the opening "$" sign for the absolute cell reference.
- `REGEXEXTRACT(ADDRESS(row(), Column()),"[A-Z]+")` - returns the column letter for the current column ([Convert column index into corresponding column letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129496/1330560) on StackOverflow)
- `&"$"&`- Adds the closing "$" sign for the absolute cell reference.
- `column()` - This creates a value equal to the row number required in each column.

---

**SAMPLE REPORT**

[image: report]

---

**WEEKS- WN01-WN03**

[image: Week1]
[image: Week2]
[image: Week3]